# Object passed to method in java works on original copy

Tags: java, object, reference, biginteger

I have `Sample` class with one field and I am doing following things:

1. Calling method with object of this class as a parameter.
2. Make some operations on this object.
3. Original object got changed after all.

I am doing same thing with `BigInteger` class object and it works different. Why is that so?

My class:

```
public class Sample {
    private int number;

    public int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Sample add(int number){
        this.number += number;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Invocation:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("5");
        Sample s1 = new Sample();
        s1.setNumber(3);
        System.out.println(s1.getNumber());
        Sample s2 = m.checkSample(s1);
        BigInteger b2 = m.checkBig(b1);
        System.out.println(s1.getNumber()+" "+s2.getNumber());
        System.out.println(b1.toString()+" "+b2.toString());


    }
    public Sample checkSample(Sample k){
        k = k.add(5);
        return k;
    }
    public BigInteger checkBig(BigInteger big){
        big = big.add(new BigInteger("2"));
        return big;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3
8 8
5 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing the same thing with `BigInteger` - you're calling the `add` method which returns a reference to a *new* `BigInteger`, and you're assigning that value back to `big`.

Your `Sample.add` method changes the *existing* object instead:

```
public Sample add(int number){
    this.number += number;
    return this;
}
```

If you changed it to return a reference to a new object, it would behave like `BigInteger`:

```
public Sample add(int number){
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.setNumber(sample.number + number);
    return sample;
}
```

However, your `Sample` class is fundamentally *mutable* at the moment, unlike `BigInteger`. No operations on `BigInteger` change the state of an existing object; instead, they *all* create new objects. If you want to replicate that behaviour in `Sample`, you'd write it something like this:

```
public final class Sample {
    private final int number;

    public Sample(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public Sample add(int number){
        return new Sample(this.number + number);
    }
}
```

It's important to understand that you're never passing *objects* around in Java - only *references* which are used to navigate to objects. So for example:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder b = a;
b.append("hello");
System.out.println(a); // Prints hello
```

Here there's a *single* `StringBuilder` object, but both variables (`a` and `b`) have values which refer to the same object. Any changes made via one variable are still visible through the other variable. (See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933557/in-java-does-an-object-variable-contain-the-address-of-an-object/8933600#8933600) for more about this.)

Answer (score 3):

BigInteger is immutable and return a new object each time.

Your Sample class is mutable and when you alter it there is only one copy/value it holds.